# Github. Как удалить ненужные коммиты, которые уже были запушены на удаленный?

Tags: git, github

Начну с того что в спешке запушила коммит с ошибкой в тексте комментария, потом нашла в интернете что можно исправить с помощью git commit --amend -m "Новое описание", применила. В результате у меня появился новый коммит с правильным комментарием, но и старый остался. Потом я пробовала удалить его с помощью git rebase -i, но немного запуталась и отменила команду с помощью git rebase --abort. В итоге у меня добавился еще один ненужный коммит из-за rebase. Как правильно удалить их?
Мои коммиты:

```
412a9d6 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Merge branch 'master' //не нужен
81f28e5 practice with TextView and EditText
0748ba5 practice whith textView and editText  //не нужен
88f5935 studied the types and characteristics of the view
74e9131 init project
```

Comment: А зачем? При разработке это нормально

Comment: @RavenTheX Вы правы, наверное можно оставить все как есть, тем более с этим проектом работаю только я, а точнее учусь программировать. Но для себя хотелось бы все-таки знать

Comment: ну вы пытались правильно, с помощью `git rebase -i` вы можете "схлопнуть" все ненужные комиты в один и назвать его правильно